# chemmacros and dots

Tags: chemmacros

I am trying to write chemical equation with `\usepackage{chemmacros}` but I have a problem.

I want something like that

```
$...Al + Fe_2O_3 \longrightarrow ...Fe + Al_2O_3$
```

The dots are for my students.

When I write

```
\ch{..Fe{} + ...O2 -> Fe3O4}
```

it's a mess.

Anybody have a solution?

Comment: `\ldots` or `\dots`?

Comment: \ldots works ! great thx :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a dot is part of a formula or is a single dot (i.e. separated by spaces from other formula parts) it is interpreted as an adduct:

```
\ch{Na2SO4. 10 H2O}
```

[image]

The same will happen to consecutive dots `\ch{...}`.

If it is only together with numbers it is interpreted as the decimal mark:

```
\ch{1.5 Fe}
```

[image]

Here are three possibilities achieving what you want, one of them being simply `\ldots` as mentioned in the comments. The first version (which I wouldn't use as it looks not so nice) uses `chemformula`'s escaping between `" "`. The third version uses the *math escaping* where `chemformula` adds the same space after it as after a stoichiometric factor (this could be changed with the `math-space` option).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  manual solution (looks bad IMHO) &
  \ch{"..." Fe + "..." O2 -> Fe3O4} \\
  \texttt{\string\ldots} &
  \ch{\ldots Fe + \ldots O2 -> Fe3O4} \\
  with spacing of stoichiometric factor &
  \ch{$\ldots{}$ Fe + $\ldots{}$ O2 -> Fe3O4}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great thx to you :)

Comment: @michaelb you're welcome! :) If the answer helped you may consider [voting for it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) or even [accepting it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)...

Comment: how to ? (my english is a mess too...)

Comment: @michaelb First of all: it is of course fully up to you if you want to vote or accept! You vote by clicking on the up arrow on the left side of a question or answer (or - if a post is wrong or really bad - on the down arrow). You accept by clicking the check mark below the arrows.

Comment: done (i hope...)